# MapStruct - How to specify generic type of an attribute?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Mapstruct can't find generic type of an attribute. Let's take an example to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Considering the following dtos :

```
class ListForm<T> {
 private Collection<T> adds;
 private Collection<T> changes;
 private Collection<T> deletes;
}

class Person {
 private String name;
}

class PersonDto { 
 private String name;
}
```

I try to implement the following mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface OccupantMapper {
    ListForm<Person> test(ListForm<PersonDto> person);

    Collection<Person> toPersons (Collection<PersonDto> persons);
}
```

But here is a part of what mapstruct generates :

```
ListForm<Person> listForm= new ListForm<Person>();
if ( occ.getAjouts() != null ) {
        if ( listForm.getAjouts() != null ) {
            // problem here, mapstruct can't find the type of the attribute
            Collection<T> targetCollection = person.getAdds();
            if ( targetCollection != null ) {
                listForm.getAjouts().addAll( targetCollection );
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see on the code below, mapstruct can't find the type of the target collection. And it doesn't to convert the list of PersonDto to a list of Person. Here is what mapstruct should generates.

```
Collection<Occupant> targetCollection = toPersons(person.getAdds());
```

Can you tell me if it's a bug? If there a fix? Or should I do it differently?
Thks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been corrected in the MapStruct 1.1.0.Beta1 released

Answer (score 0):

Can you build MapStruct from the latest master (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct) yourself and see whether this fixes the problem for  you? I fixed a related bug last week which I think was essentially the same issue as yours.

You just need to run "mvn clean install" and refer to the SNAPSHOT version of the dependency in your project.